# Htaccess issue and bad flag delimiters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i'm new to htaccess and I was searching any solution for hours. So far nothing works. What's wrong here?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/.]+)/?$ articles.php?topic=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^ articles/$ articles.php?topic= [L]
```

And many other rules.

If I change line 4 to (remove space):

```
RewriteRule ^index.php [L]
```

It gives me not found error.

If I change line 5:

```
RewriteRule ^ articles/$ articles.php?topic= [L]
```

It gives bad flag delimiters.

I'm using MAMP.
Thanks!

EDIT: The first rule is from this tutorial:
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/

I'm trying to add the second one to change this:

... site/articles.php?topic=historical-background

To this:

... site/articles/historical-background

But nothing happens or I get one of the errors mentioned above.

EDIT 2:

My index file:

```
include('template/header.php'); 
include('views/'page.php'); 
include('template/footer.php');
```

page.php (in root/views folder):

...

```
if ($page['id'] == 15) { ?>  // id of articles page
<div class="content_container"> <?php 
include('views/articles_list.php');  
?>
</div>
<?php 
}
```

...

articles_list.php (in root/views folder). It displays list of articles:

...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>  
<h2><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
<p><i><?php echo 'By '.$row['author']; ?></i></p>
<p><?php echo $row['header']; ?></p>
<a href="http://localhost/site/articles.php?topic=<?php echo $row['slug'] ?>">Read</a><br> //I get to article.php from here.
<hr>
<?php
}
?>
```

...

articles.php is in the root folder. It shows chosen article.
htaccess is also in the root.

Comment: No error. I'm still on articles page (list of articles not specific article). No matter what I type after articles/ I still get the content of http://domain.com/articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to disable `MultiViews` here and rearrange your rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+articles\.php\?topic=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ articles/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^articles/([^/.]+)/?$ articles.php?topic=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: No error, but I see the content of http://domain.com/articles/ not the http://domain.com/articles/historical-background. No matter what I tape after articles/ I still get the content of http://domain.com/articles/  .htaccess is in the root folder

Comment: Now when I type http://localhost/site/articles/historical-background I get what I want :) But when I click the link <a href="http://localhost/site/articles.php?topic=<?php echo $row['slug'] ?>">Read</a> it doesn't change to http://domain.com/articles/historical-background